Is it possible to cancel old Github Action runs but keep the one in progress?
I have a Github Actions job that runs terraform when there is a push on the main branch. Now I have it configured with
concurrency:
  group: my-job
  cancel-in-progress: true

But as the name says, it will cancel a job in the middle of the run, causing a state lock.
If I have a couple jobs queued I would like to keep running a job if it already started and only run the newest of the queued ones. Is that possible? Or somehow avoid the state lock

With cancel-in-progress: false, the running job will never be cancelled, but all but the most recent waiting job are skipped, would that work?

Yes, that is what I needed. Thanks!
